# Is there any way to get an html content/value with php?

Tags: php

Can i get the content or value of the tag with php?
I know i can get it with javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('class or id').text();
});
```

But i would like to get it with php, so i can send it back in another query to my sql table.

```
function changeContentToId(id) {
    $("#spanContent").html(id); }

<?php echo "<span onclick='changeContentToId($ob->ID)'>...</span>"; ?>
<span id="spanContent"></span>
```

This is my code right now, any tips on how to write the top code in php?

thanks. :)

Comment: There was another question like this, but i did not really get that much from the answers..

Comment: I don't really understand the question... if you are generating the page with PHP you have to content already, or not? Or are you crawling a page and what to analyse its content? Your question is far from being clear.

Comment: I don't think the question deserves a downvote.

Comment: this is a bad idea! any tom dick or harry can edit the front end using tools like firebug ect. If you then process that data directly into the database then you will have problems!

Comment: I were only going to check the if the content was equal to a value in my database and then print what is needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

No way : PHP is server-side, and your data is on the client.

Then you have 2 alternatives : getting the information before sending it to the browser (output buffering is a good way), or after, via an AJAX call.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you send it in a 'normal' way ? Like putting the content inside a form then submit it to PHP.

Or get it using Javascript then submit it using AJAX.

PHP won't access client-side information(HTML) once it is in your client(after the content is delivered) you can use client-side manipulation(Javascript) or send it back to server then use it there.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you cannot do that.  PHP is executed on the server **before** the page is rendered.  JavaScript, which updates the content, is executed in the browser **after** the page is rendered.  Hence by the time your content is ready to be read, there is no PHP any more.

The way around it would be to use AJAX to read the info with JavaScript and then send it to another PHP script.

Comment: Yes, the php is executed on the server, and the "html element" gets it's content on the server. But if the content it recives = the content of the sql table, it should be doable?  nvm

Comment: If you have that content before the page is rendered, then why do you need to get it that way?  Surely there'll be a variable or something with that information.

Answer (score 0):

get it with javascript and send it uing ajax to the server.

Just if you really need to, because i don't see any reason since it's generated with php the first time. so you should use the word you want before rendring the html page.